# Creating System Level Environmental Variables Manually

Tags: vb.net

How do one create System Level environmental variables manually. I just installed a GeoSupport Desktop Edition software and in the document it is mentioned that I need to
create system-level environmental
variables for PATH and GEOFILES manually

Add the location of the GDE executables to the system-level environmental variable PATH.
Normally this means adding C:\Program Files\Geosupport Desktop Edition\bin to the PATH.

How an I do that??

Comment: It depends upon the operating system. (Not technically a programming question, too.)

Comment: @Michael Todd: It doesn't depend on the OS, since its a built in Framework feature.

Comment: @David Sure it depends upon the OS, if the person isn't using a programming language to do it (which _sounds_ like the case here).

Comment: If you're trying to do this in XP from the OS level, this should work: ( http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm ). Answer is about halfway down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways, all of them included in this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/01/03/50984.aspx

They're for C#, but translating should be trivial.

Comment: I don't think (hard to tell from the info provided) that the OP is trying to program it. Hopefully he/she will be able to glean the proper steps from your link.

Comment: The only reason I thought it was to be programmed is because of the vb.net tag. You're probably right though.